# ngFor Directive Not Found

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I am using Angular 4.3.3 with the JIT compiler and get the error below when I run my application:

> Property binding `ngforOf` not used by any directive on an embedded template.
> Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the `@NgModule.declarations`.

I have made sure to import the `BrowserModule` in my main app module and I've imported the `CommonModule` in my child module that this error is originating from.

Here is the template that throws the error:

```
<div class="background"></div>
<div class="content normal-page">
    <ons-fab position="top right" ripple>+</ons-fab>
    <ons-list>
        <ons-list-item *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
            <div class="center">
                #{{i}} msg: {{item.msg}}
            </div>
        </ons-list-item>
    </ons-list>
</div>
```

Since I am importing the proper modules into the right places what could be causing this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out the problem, I had webpack minimizing my templates. Once I turned minimizing off then it works fine.

```
{
    test: /\.html$/,
    use: [
        {
            loader: 'html-loader',
            options: {
                minimize: false
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: but where should i update above minimize option tell me file name once.

Answer (score 29):

The NgModule that contains your component needs to have `CommonModule` in `imports`

```
@NgModule({
  ...,
  imports: [CommonModule],
})
export class MySharedModule {}
```

Also `binding ngforOf not used` indicates that you are using `*ngfor` instead of `*ngFor` with capital `F`.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have `*ngfor` somewhere in your code instead of `*ngFor` (with capital `F`)?

Comment: I figured out the problem, see my answer. It was a webpack issue. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: I saw, that explains why it all got lowercased.

Comment: I see. Sorry, Seems I accidentally skipped that line.

Answer (score 21):

Sometimes it could happen when you forgot the `let` in the for like:

```
<span *ngFor="teacher of teachers">{{teacher}}</span>
```

And it should be:

```
<span *ngFor="let teacher of teachers">{{teacher}}</span>
```

Comment: This has just been my typo, hadn't even realized, thanks!

Answer (score 17):

Sometimes it can happen when you use

*ngFor="let data in dataList">{{data}}

Try changing it to

*ngFor="let data of dataList">{{data}}

You need to replace 'in' by 'of'.

Comment: turns out this was my mistake

Comment: This also fixed it for me using Angular 17.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using standalone components with Angular 14 or 15, you can import CommonModule into you component or deconstruct and grab NgForOf:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'
import {Link} from "./link";
import {Container} from "./container";
import {menu} from "../../db/db";
import {NgFor, NgForOf} from "@angular/common";
@Component({
  selector: 'navigation',
  template: `
    <nav class="bg-white border-b border-gray-100">
      <container>
       <ul class="flex space-x-5">
            <li *ngFor="let link of menu">
            <nav-link href="">{{link.name}}</nav-link>
            </li>
        </ul>
      </container>
    </nav>
  `,
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
      Link, 
      Container, 
      NgForOf
      ],
   }) export class Navigation { 
      menu = menu;
   }
```

Comment: Do you know why can't I import CommonModule into BootstrapApplication(RootCmp, {importProvidersFrom(CommonModule)}), what is the difference between the example I am providing and your example which worked for me?

Comment: You cannot because at this  point you are bootstrapping the application and CommonModule is feature oriented, not Root oriented. As we used to do before with AppModule, you would have BrowserModule from @angular/platform-browser during bootstrap which already imports CommonModule.

Answer (score 0):

add app.module.ts :

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
    ],


})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to ensure that the component you're working on is declared in your `module.ts` file.

e.g. In your Component while where you're using the `*ngFor:`

```
@Component({
  ...
  template: '<div *ngFor="let thing of things">..</div>'
})
export class MyComponent {...
```

This component must also be declared in your `module.ts file`:

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  declarations: [
    MyComponent
  ]
```

I use a VS Code extension that creates my components for me, but doesn't register them in the app module, and I often forget to do it manually, causing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was I wrote 'as' instead of 'of'

```
let o of options
```

Basically, any syntax error like missing let, not capitalizing ngFor, or writing 'as' can cause this.

Answer (score -1):

In Ionic 6, in my home page I needed to add CommonModule:

```js
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
...
  imports: [CommonModule]
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit {
```

I'm using blank template. If you are using page with modules, you'll need to add CommonModule in your page module.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You just have to include `imports: [CommonModule],` in your @Component Section.

```
@Component({
selector: 'courses', //This is a css selector. If <div class="courses"> selector='.courses'
                         //if <div id="courses"> selector='#courses'
standalone: true,
imports: [CommonModule],
template: `
<h2>{{ title }}</h2>
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let course of courses">
        {{course}}
    </li>
</ul>`,
```

})

Comment: I am learning Angular and I encountered this error recently and this is how I solve the error.

Comment: The question states that the module has been imported.